# Proving something with Wilson theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity

I need to prove that $x^2\equiv -1\pmod p$ if $p=4n+1$.

($p$ is prime of course...)

I need to use Wilson theorem.

Comment: The answer by  Michalis to the linked question is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have, $p-r\equiv-r\pmod p$

Putting $r=1,2,\cdots,\frac{p-1}2$  and multiplying we get $$\prod_{1\le r\le \frac{p-1}2}(p-r)\equiv(-1)^{\frac{p-1}2}\prod_{1\le r\le \frac{p-1}2} r$$

Multiplying either sides by $\prod_{1\le r\le \frac{p-1}2} r$

$$(p-1)!\equiv(-1)^{\frac{p-1}2}\left(\prod_{1\le r\le \frac{p-1}2} r\right)^2\pmod p$$

Wilson theorem says: $(p-1)!\equiv-1\pmod p$

If $p=1+4n, \frac{p-1}2=2n$ which is even $\implies (-1)^{\frac{p-1}2}=\cdots$

Comment: Thank you!! but where you mention the $x^2$??

Comment: The second term on the RHS is square, get it?

Comment: and at the $(-1)^{2n}$ it's always 1, yes?
But we had to proof the it is -1,right? Thank you!

Comment: @Stefan4024, I'm sorry, but no...
I didn't understand where is the $x^2$...

Comment: Actually this is the "homework" @lab bhattavharjee gave you. First denote $\prod_{1\le r\le \frac{p-1}{2}} r = x$, so the congruence relation becomes:

$$(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}x^2 \equiv (p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod p$$

Can you obtain from this why $(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} = 1$? Take a look at the first line of your question.

P.S. LHS means Left-Hand Side, and RHS means Right-Hand Side

Comment: becuse -1 will be 1 at even power, right?
and 2n it's an even power.

Comment: And I still didn't understand where is the $x^2$...

Comment: @YoavFridman Denote the product as $x$. That's $x$.

Comment: OK, and why we get $(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$?
I don't understand the RHS at this (the formula at the third line).

Comment: As lab said $r=1,2,...,\frac{p-1}{2}$ then we have:

$$p - 1 \equiv -1 \pmod p$$
$$p - 2 \equiv -2 \pmod p$$
$$\cdots$$
$$p - \frac{p-1}{2} \equiv -\frac{p-1}{2} \pmod p$$

Multiply all LHS and all RHS and the RHS will become:

$$RHS = (-1)(-2)(-3)...(-\frac{p-1}{2}) = (-1)(1)(-1)(2)(-1)(3)...(-1)(\frac{p-1}{2})$$

Because we have $\frac{p-1}{2}$ terms on the right the exponent for $(-1)$ is $\frac{p-1}{2}$

Comment: @Stefan4024, thanks a lot for your explanations

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I'll do anything in my powers to make things clearer to other users

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still don't understand where is the $x^2$...
sorry for all of my Q...

Comment: But $\left(-1\right)^{\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)}=1$ [Because the exponent is even]. So why @labbhattacharjee says it's -1, I didn't understand this...

Comment: If $p=1+4n,$
$$-1\equiv\left(\prod_{1\le r\le \frac{p-1}2} r\right)^2\pmod p,$$ right?

Answer (score 1):

The following argument is closely related to the one given by lab bhattacharjee, but is easier to type. It goes back at least to Dirichlet.

Note that for every $x$ between $1$ and $p-1$, there is a unique $y$ such that $xy\equiv -1\pmod{p}$: for $y$ is just the negative of the inverse of $x$.

Call the $y$ such that $xy\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ the **partner** of $x$. (Dirichlet did not use the term partner, that is a more modern notion.)

We want to show that there is an $x$ which is its own partner. (There are actually two.) Such an $x$ will satisfy $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$.

Suppose to the contrary that no one is his own partner. Then the numbers $1$ to $p-1$ are divided into $2n$ couples, each of which has product $\equiv -1\pmod{p}$. Thus $(p-1)!\equiv (-1)^{2n}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. This **contradicts** Wilson's Theorem, and the result follows.

**Remark:** The same idea can be used to show that if $p$ is of the form $4n+3$, then the congruence $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ has no solution. (There are simpler ways to do that.)

For it is easy to see if the congruence $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ has a solution $s$, then it has exactly two solutions, $s$ and $-s$. Then $(s)(-s)\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. The other $4n$ numbers between $1$ and $p-1$ are divided into $2n$ pairs of partners, each of which has product congruent to $-1$. Thus $(p-1)!\equiv (-1)^{2n}(s)(-s)\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, again contradicting Wilson's Theorem.