# Proving something with Wilson's Theorem [continued.]

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity

At first I asked this: [Proving something with Wilson theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/547191/proving-something-with-wilson-theorem).

Now I have to prove that if $p=4n+3$ it's impossible to represent $-1$ in the form $x^2$ modulo $p$. How can I prove it?

Thank you!

Comment: Please show us your attempt.

Comment: Also, it would be much better to say what precisely is supposed to be impossible (in this post).

Comment: Do some research on Legendre symbols first.

Comment: If you have a square root of $-1$, such an element is of order four in $\Bbb{Z}_p^*$. What does Lagrange say about that?

Comment: I get - $p=3+4n=2n-1$. why this impossible (at the contact of Wilson theorem)? I don't understand... Please help me...
Thank you!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen - we didn't learn it. we have to use Wilson theorem...

Comment: **Hint:** Use [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem).

Comment: @IvanLoh, But how? Where Fermat's little theorem can help me here??
Thank you!

Comment: You do realise that @Feanor has already posted an answer which uses Fermat's little theorem, right?

Comment: Right!!
Thank you, If still I wont understand something, I'll ask!
Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is generally true that $a$ is a quadratic remainder (i.e. is of the form $x^2$ for some $x$) if and only if $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$. Once you know this, just note that for $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ you have $(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} = -1$ and you are done.

Because you only need to show that $-1$ is *not* a quadratic residue, it will suffice to show one implication (the easy one). So, suppose that $a = x^2$ and  $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$. We get by substituting one equation to another that $x^{p-1} \equiv  -1 \pmod{p}$. But this is in contradiction with Fermat's theorem, which finishes the proof.